# Access to authenticated users only

Tags: .net, forms-authentication

I want my users to access the some pages after authentication only. After some reading on the internet I found two ways of doing it:

1. Add [Authorize] in the controller method calling the page.
2. Create a sub-folder in the Views folder and add
       `<authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>`  in the sub-folder's web.config.

The first method works.  But not the second method.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The first method adds authorization functionality to the Action method that returns your page.

I haven't used the second method but from what I [see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx) it is used in an authorization manner. Not Authentication. And it is in a page level. I wouldn't try to implement Authentication (since this is what I think you want to do) with this way.